# Pretty print for a groovy ConfigObject?

Tags: java, groovy, formatting, configuration-files

I have this groovy program that creates a groovy configuration file, using a ConfigObject. Once the ConfigObject is set up, it is written to a file using:

```
myFile.withWriter {writer -> myConfigObject.writeTo(writer)}
```

This results in each property of the ConfigObject being written on a single line. So for instance a map will be printed as:

```
graphs=[["type":"std", "host":"localhost", "name":"cpurawlinux"], ["type":"std", "host":"localhost", "name":"memory"], ["type":"std", "host":"localhost", "name":"udp"] ... ]
```

which is quite unreadable if someone has to take a look at it.
Is there a way to get a more friendly output? Something like that would be great:

```
graphs=[
    ["type":"std", "host":"localhost", "name":"cpurawlinux"],
    ["type":"std", "host":"localhost", "name":"memory"],
    ["type":"std", "host":"localhost", "name":"udp"]
    ...
]
```

I know I could create my own `writeTo`, but isn't there already something in Groovy for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you'll need to write your own `writeTo` as you say.

If you have a config file with structure like:

```
graphs {
  a=["type":"std", "host":"localhost", "name":"cpurawlinux"]
  b=["type":"std", "host":"localhost", "name":"memory"]
}
```

Then writeTo will write it out with structure, but if your config file is just a big old list of things, it will write it out as a big old list

Answer (score 1):

if it helps anyone, i had the same question and wrote this...not pretty (ha), but works:

```
def prettyPrint(properties, level=1, stringBuilder = new StringBuilder()) {
    return properties.inject(stringBuilder) { sb, name, value ->
        sb.append("\n").append("\t" * level).append(name)
        if (!(value instanceof Map) && !(value instanceof List)) {
            return sb.append("=").append(value)
        } else {
            return prettyPrint(properties.getProperty(name), level+1, sb)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on mike's answer above:

```
def prettyPrint
prettyPrint = {obj, level = 0, sb = new StringBuilder() ->
    def indent = { lev -> sb.append("  " * lev) }
    if(obj instanceof Map){
        sb.append("{\n")
        obj.each{ name, value ->
            if(name.contains('.')) return // skip keys like "a.b.c", which are redundant
            indent(level+1).append(name)
            (value instanceof Map) ? sb.append(" ") : sb.append(" = ")
            prettyPrint(value, level+1, sb)
            sb.append("\n")
        }
        indent(level).append("}")
    }
    else if(obj instanceof List){
        sb.append("[\n")
        obj.each{ value ->
            indent(level+1)
            prettyPrint(value, level+1, sb).append(",")
            sb.append("\n")
        }
        indent(level).append("]")
    }
    else if(obj instanceof String){
        sb.append('"').append(obj).append('"')
    }
    else {
        sb.append(obj)
    }
}
```

For an input like:

```
{
  grails {
    scaffolding {
      templates.domainSuffix = "Instance"
    }
    enable {
      native2ascii = true
      blah = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
    }
    mime.disable.accept.header.userAgents = [ "WebKit", "Presto", "Trident" ]
  }
}
```

Produces:

```
{
  grails {
    scaffolding {
      templates {
        domainSuffix = "Instance"
      }
    }
    enable {
      native2ascii = true
      blah = [
        1,
        2,
        3,
      ]
    }
    mime {
      disable {
        accept {
          header {
            userAgents = [
              "WebKit",
              "Presto",
              "Trident",
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since GreenGiant answer seems broken when I tried using it, here's a working version for future reference :

```
static String prettify(obj, level = 0, StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder()) {
    def indent = { lev -> sb.append("  " * lev) }
    if (!obj) return sb
    if(obj instanceof Map<String, ?>){
        sb.append("{\n")
        obj.each{ name, value ->
            if(name.contains('.')) return // skip keys like "a.b.c", which are redundant
            indent(level+1).append(name)
            (value instanceof Map) ? sb.append(" ") : sb.append(" = ")
            prettify(value, level+1, sb)
            sb.append("\n")
        }
        indent(level).append("}")
    } else if(obj instanceof List){
        sb.append("[\n")
        obj.each{ value ->
            indent(level+1)
            prettify(value, level+1, sb).append(",")
            sb.append("\n")
        }
        indent(level).append("]")
    } else if(obj instanceof String){
        sb.append('"').append(obj).append('"')
    } else {
        sb.append(obj)
    }
}
```